# where to get java SDK for BusinessObjects

Tags: java, import, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I want to import the packages, for example:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

these packages have already existed so it doesn't pop up any error messages.
When I want to import others packages:

```
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.DocumentInstance;
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.Prompt;
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.Prompts;
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngine;
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines;
import com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceNames;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.CrystalEnterprise;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.IEnterpriseSession;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.ISessionMgr;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoObject;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoObjects;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoStore;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.desktop.folder.IFolder;
```

It will say "the import cannot be resolved", but where I can get the jar files to resolve these problems?

I tried to search these jar files in the java lib folder but was not able to get them.

Can anyone tell the exact folder path for these jar files, if it is there?
Or where can I download those packages.....
I found the website (https://help.sap.com/doc/javadocs_bip_42/4.2/en-US/bip/en/com/crystaldecisions/sdk/exception/package-summary.html) but I still don't know how to import it......

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `rebean.wi.adapter.jar` and `cecore.jar`.  They are located in the following directory with BO client or server software is installed:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\lib`

Note that these are not available publicly -- you will need to install the software.

Comment: It worked!
Thank you so much!